# If God is a God of love, why does God not make all souls in hell cease to exist?

Tags: soteriology, hell, annihilationism

If God is omnipotent, and a God of love, why does God not make all souls in hell cease to exist, and did it ever happen? Also, wouldn't a loving God end their suffering? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There is a branch of theology called annihilationism that suggests something along that line. Perhaps you'd like to research that and ask a question about it. As of right now this question is not particularly constructive. Largely because answers vary a great deal depending on who you ask.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of a question that Dan Andrews asked a few weeks back - along the lines Wouldn't it be nicer  of God to not create life in the first place...